# Inline Visualforce API issue

Tags: api, visualforce-component, app

I have asked this question of Salesforce support from my partner portal but they closed it without answering (which I am trying to deal with as a separate matter), but it is affecting my client's use of their org, so I was wondering if any of you have seen it.

We are having weird issues with two apps, Mailchimp and AAKonsult. (These are the only two apps that use the API that are installed so far). The issue is with these apps accessing their servers via the API.
I had contacted Mailchimp support believing it to be an issue on their end, but since it is now affecting AAKonsult also, it is definitely a Salesforce issue.

All page layouts with the MC4SF Visualforce pages on the layouts are displaying the record for a few seconds and then redirecting to a non existent URL. (when it's just trying to display the Mailchimp section on the page). The URL is trying to go to mc4sf.ap1.visual.force.com.

The same thing happens when trying to display a record in the AAKonsult Payments app and it is trying to communicate with aakpay.ap1.visual.force.com.

Exact replication steps:
Open a record that has an inline visualforce component on the page layou. 
Wait for the page to completely finish loading.
The status bar in the bottom left corner of the browser says "waiting for secure connection" then tries to go to aakpay.ap1.visual.force.com or mc4sf.ap1.visual.force.com then goes to the page https://ap1.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.Integration?lid=XXXXXXXXXXXXX&ic=1 and says URL No Longer exists.

There are no errors recorded in the debug logs in either case.
There is no issue with API Limits.
There is nothing showing up on your system status site saying that AP1 is having any issues.
Today I have uninstalled mailchimp and reinstalled it. The issue is still there - so it is NOT an app issue.
This is in a live org, not a sandbox.

Comment: Yes, i agree with you @JodieM. I too experienced this issue if not recurrently but intermittently. i too waiting for someone with some inputs here..

Comment: While it does sound like a Salesforce issue since it's happening on multiple packages, I would contact the vendors' help channels also to see if they're seeing the issue anywhere else.

Comment: Yes @RayDehler it was the first thing I did. Got on Twitter and asked if anyone else in the world was having problems with Mailchimp. I have reached out to both vendors, had contact back from the top level guys at Mailchimp and no one else is reported it. It is an org specific thing because I have other orgs using the same apps with no problems. I was hoping putting it on here may be helpful becuase it may be something devs have come across before.

Comment: Has anyone noticed that the MailChimp App uses iFrames?
I thought iFrames did not work if you have 'ClickJack' protection enabled, but with our Org they do...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, it looks like I was the idiot that caused this issue. I checked the new setting that came in in a recent release, thinking it was the safest thing to do.

For anyone else coming across this issue... from Salesforce support:

As per the article

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=VisualForce-components-in-Page-Layouts-causing-URL-No-Longer-Exists-error&language=en_US

You will be redirected to 'URL No Longer Exist' page if you embedded the visualforce page in a page layout, if 'clickjack protection for non-setup customer Visualforce pages' is enabled in your org.

And when I checked your org, the permission 'Clickjack protection for non-setup customer Visualforce pages' has been enabled. Once I disable the feature, you are able to see the records properly.